# Read current audio output - Android

Tags: java, android, audio

I want to know if it is possible to access the audio that is currently playing on the Android device.

**Example**: if Spotify is running in the background, I want to access the audio to control some `LEDs` that are connected to my `RaspberryPi`.

I want to create some sort of equalizer that changes colors depending on the sound that is currently playing. I appreciate if some one could tell me if accessing the main audio output is possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using a rooted phone, it's not possible to capture output of a random app on Android.

You can however create an app that plays media files and captures the output for the purpose of visualization with "Visualizer" effect. You can take a look on the sample here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.java
(look for "Visualizer").

If you are using Raspberry Pi anyway, you can just play all your music **through** it, capture and analyze it there. You will need an external USB sound card though. See for example this post: http://www.g7smy.co.uk/2013/08/recording-sound-on-the-raspberry-pi/
There they just record and play audio back, but you can insert an analysis phase in between.